# RecyclerView Adapter instrumentation test with ViewBinding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-instrumentation, android-viewbinding

I have a RecyclerView Adapter with multiple ViewHolders. Each ViewHolder uses a ViewBinding Class to inflate the view. I am trying to write some test for the adapter class. Here is my test class.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class HomeTest {

private lateinit var adapter: Adapterr

@Before
fun setup() {
    adapter = Adapterr()
}

@Test
fun createViewHolder() {
    adapter.updateAdapter(getDummyAdapterItems())
    //Error happens on this line.
    val p = RecyclerView(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context)
    p.adapter = adapter

    val viewHolder = adapter.onCreateViewHolder(p, 0)

    assertThat(viewHolder, notNullValue())
}
```

I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.view.View.retrieveExplicitStyle [class android.content.res.Resources$Theme, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
at io.mockk.proxy.android.MethodDescriptor.getMethod(MethodDescriptor.kt:22)
at io.mockk.proxy.android.advice.Advice.getOrigin(Advice.kt:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at io.mockk.proxy.android.AndroidMockKDispatcher.getOrigin(AndroidMockKDispatcher.java:117)
at android.view.View.retrieveExplicitStyle(Unknown Source:14)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5474)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:693)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:654)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:650)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:646)
at com.example.home.HomeTest.createViewHolder(HomeTest.kt:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2205)
```

I even tried running it with a MockViewGroup Object, but I get the same error.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem?